# Quick deploy standalone PHP script to accept uploaded files?

Tags: php, file-upload

I need to accept a large number of images from a 3rd party, and I already have an apache server up and running. As the 3rd party is not tech-savvy, I would like to give them a simple web form to upload files.

They don't need to be able to access the files they've uploaded, although I suppose it would be nice for them to verify what they've already sent, especially being that there is a large number of files.

There is also no requirement to be able to upload all files at once, and I think I can talk them through packaging the files into a 4-5 zip files, so single upload would be acceptable.

If I need to write a PHP script myself then so be it, but I was wondering if such a standalone script already exists in the wild, nice and polished etc :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice ajax file manager:

http://www.ajaxplorer.info/wordpress/demo/

Others:

http://devsnippets.com/article/7-free-powerful-file-managers.html